# Firebase for a Web Application

Tags: database, database-design, firebase

I am currently working on a new Web Application. I really love the idea behind firebase (augularfire) for the realtime data sync. But I can't figure out how to organize all the data, make each customer (enterprise) have his own data, and ensure no data is shared between each enterprise.

In a regular MySql server, I can create a database per enterprise (best implementation for speed and security) or simply add a table Enterprise and a table Customer with enterprise_id. Which is the best approach in a Firebase DB?

Comment: Recommending the best approach for almost anything is incredibly broad. But one way you could shard multiple tenants into a NoSQL database like Firebase is to make each customer their own top-level node. So `/customer1/data_for_customer1`, `/customer2/data_for_customer2`, etc.